# Why adding a dot in import_module() avoids ImportError?

Tags: python, import, built-in, python-importlib

Having the following directory tree:

<sub>**Note**: The following behavior is the same with/without the `__init__.py` files.</sub>

```
top_package
|   top_module.py
|
+---package1
|   |   module1.py
|   |   __init__.py
|
\---package2
    |   module2.py
    |   __init__.py
```

with `top_module.py`:

```py
from package1.module1 import CLASS1


a = CLASS1()
```

`module1.py`:

```py
from importlib import import_module


class CLASS1:

    def __init__(self):
        # this works:
        foo = getattr(
            import_module(name='..module2', package='package2.'), 'CLASS2')()
        
        # this raises ImportError.
        foo = getattr(
            import_module(name='..module2', package='package2'), 'CLASS2')()
```

In which the unique difference is that the first uses a dot when defining the package arg. (`package='package2.'`), while the other doesn't (`package='package2'`).

`module2.py`:

```py
class CLASS2:

    def __init__(self):
        print(f'hi from: {__name__}')
```

I am having a hard time understanding why in `module1.py` the first assignment for `foo` works, while the next one doesn't, raising `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

This error occurs when running `top_module.py` from its directory:

```bash
cd <path-to-top_package>/top_package
python top_module.py
```

The related info from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) states

> `importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`
>
> > Import a module. The *name* argument specifies what module to import in absolute or relative terms (e.g. either `pkg.mod` or `..mod`). If the name is specified in relative terms, then the *package* argument must be set to the name of the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name (e.g. `import_module('..mod', 'pkg.subpkg')` will import `pkg.mod`).

which may already be answering my question but I don't get it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrongly using `import_module`. The main reason is that if `name` specifies a *relative* module, then it is relative w.r.t. the argument `package`.

I wrongly thought that `name` was relative to the module's `__file__` value in which `import_module` is called (in this case `module1.py`).

Thereby, the first version:

```py
import_module(name='..module2', package='package2.')
```

Imports `package2.module2` since `..module2` specifies that the module is in the parent of the `package` arg. The parent of `package2.` is `package2`.

However,

```py
import_module(name='..module2', package='package2')
```

tries to import from the parent of `package2`, which is unknown, causing `ImportError`.